# Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS doesn't start after upgrade on brand new laptop

Tags: system-installation, upgrade

I have a brand new laptop:

Lenovo Legion Y540
Memory: 16GB
i7 2.6GHz
500GB

I deleted Windows and installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, which I have on a pen drive.

> sudo apt-get update

works fine and when rebooting, Ubuntu starts fine.

However, after running

> sudo apt-get upgrade

and rebooting, Ubuntu does not start.

After the Lenovo start screen, the screen freezes with a black screen and a greenish/purplish horizontal line across the top of the screen. At this point, I have to force a shut down by holding the on-off button and reinstall Ubuntu.

I didn't do anything else on the laptop, and I did this quite a few times now, with reliable results.

What should I do?

Comment: Is there an Nvidia?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: There are so much info in that link that I struggle to understand what to do. I do apparently have an Nvidia: myname@myname-Legion-Y540-17IRH:~$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2191 (rev a1)

Comment: So the problem is with Nvidia drivers. You can always boot with a previous kernel too.

Comment: The instructions I find on installing Nvidia drivers start with updating and upgrading, which I can't do for the reasons listed above. In any case, some sources strongly recommend against it. The instructions I find on booting with a previous kernel (don't know what that means) also don't work. So I'm more confused than before. A link to instructions would be much appreciated!